# Grails ; remoteFunction with dynamical update cause null in HTML page

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy

I have an issue concerning the use of a remoteFunction component in java script function ; I am using Grails 1.3.7.

I have few div in a page which contain a div I want to update. Each div I want to update has its own id (fullUrlSaProfilDivX) where X is and unique ID in the page.

I want to update two div (one after one).

I created a java script function :

```
<g:javascript>
function removeSelectedProfilAssoc(urlSaId, profilAssocId) {
    ${ remoteFunction (action:"delete", update:'fullUrlSaProfilDiv'+urlSaId, controller:"profilAssoc", params:'\'id=\'+profilAssocId', options:[asynchronous:false]) };
    ${ remoteFunction (action:"listUrlSaProfil", controller:"profilAssoc", update:'lightUrlSaProfilDiv'+urlSaId, params:'\'urlSa.id=\'+urlSaId') };
};
</g:javascript>
```

Called by a  link :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icons_delete" onclick="removeSelectedProfilAssoc(${profilAssocInstance?.urlSa?.id}, ${profilAssocInstance?.id})"></a>
```

I want to update the div linked with the button (linkage with unique id).

I can't figure out why in the generated page I got null instead of the id and the div is not refresh :

```
function removeSelectedProfilAssoc(urlSaId, profilAssocId) {
    new Ajax.Updater('fullUrlSaProfilDivnull','/_Pong2WAR/profilAssoc/delete',{asynchronous:false,evalScripts:true,parameters:'id='+profilAssocId});;
    new Ajax.Updater('lightUrlSaProfilDivnull','/_Pong2WAR/profilAssoc/listUrlSaProfil',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'urlSa.id='+urlSaId});;
};
```

Am I doing something wrong ? How can I pass the id of the div I want to refresh and add it refreshed ?

Thank you for having a look !

Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahah, you are mixing up javascript and gsp. I did it many times also, it can be tricky to find out!

In your case `urlSaId` is a ***javascript*** var, but you are using it in a ***GSP*** function call so it will be `null`....

Unfortunatly the workaround is not easy since the remoteFunction won't let you concatenate properly the javascript variable in the update since what you want is:

```
new Ajax.Updater('fullUrlSaProfilDiv'+urlSaId,'/_Pong2WAR/profilAssoc/delete',{asynchronous:false,evalScripts:true,parameters:'id='+profilAssocId});
```

What i suggest is to build directly this `Ajax.Updater(..)` without the use of remoteFunction (or something similar):

```
<g:javascript>
  function removeSelectedProfilAssoc(urlSaId, profilAssocId) {
    new Ajax.Updater('fullUrlSaProfilDiv'+urlSaId,'${createLink(action:"delete", controller:"profilAssoc")}',{asynchronous:false,evalScripts:true,parameters:'id='+profilAssocId});
    new Ajax.Updater('lightUrlSaProfilDiv'+urlSaId,'${createLink(action:"listUrlSaProfil", controller:"profilAssoc")}',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'urlSa.id='+urlSaId});;
  };
</g:javascript>
```

On a side note now, i am always using jquery instead, it simplifies all ajax in your GSP.

Comment: Thank you ! It does what I need now.

Answer (score 0):

replace remoteFunction by

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     data:'territorio='+territorio_id+'&anho='+anho+'&id='+firstIndicador+'&div='+divId+'&divmap='+divmap, 
     url:'/observatoriograils/eje/indGeneralporAnhoyTerritorio',
     success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#'+divId).html(data);},
     error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
```

where data are the parameters, url is /url/controller/function and divId is the name of div for update